# Ошибка при передаче в репозиторий новой сущности Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с ошибкой.
проект на C# с EFCore
По части EF все прописано.

Для добавления удаления чтения данных реализован интерфейс с репозиторием.

```
  public interface IRepository<T> : IReadonlyRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    Task<Result<T>> UpdateAsync(T entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool updateNullValues = false, string? include = null);
}
```

В целом репозиторий работает. Через него работал с БД в другой части кода.

Но возникла проблема при дальнейшей работе.
Я передаю в репозиторий некоторую новую сущность entity  (CallerRequestEntity)

```
    private readonly IRepository<CallerRequestEntity> _repository;
    public SwitchViewedReportHandler(IRepository<CallerRequestEntity> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public async Task<Result<CallerRequestEntity>> Handle(SwitchViewedReportCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        return await _repository.UpdateAsync(new CallerRequestEntity()
        {
           ...
        }, cancellationToken);

    }
```

и при сборке проекта я ловлю исключение :

```
System.AggregateException: "Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[APRF.HelpService.Application.Services.Requests.ReportRequests.Commands.SwitchViewedReportCommand.SwitchViewedReportCommand,APRF.Common.Models.Result`1[APRF.HelpService.Domain.Entities.CallerRequestEntity]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: APRF.HelpService.Application.Services.Requests.ReportRequests.Commands.SwitchViewedReportCommand.SwitchViewedReportHandler': GenericArguments[0], 'APRF.HelpService.Domain.Entities.CallerRequestEntity', on 'APRF.HelpService.Repository.Repository`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.)"

TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'APRF.HelpService.Domain.Entities.CallerRequestEntity', on 'APRF.HelpService.Repository.Repository`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.
```

С чем связана эта проблема ?

UPD
содержимое CallerRequestEntity

```
       [DataContract]
[Table(Constants.Table.CallerRequestEntity)]
public class CallerRequestEntity 
{
    [Required]
    [Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.CallerId)]
    public Guid CallerId { get; set; }

[Required]
[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.UserCallEventId)]
public int UserCallEventId { get; set; }

[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.ClassificationId)]
public Guid? ClassificationId { get; set; }

[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.CallTransferDataId)]
public Guid? CallTransferDataId { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(32)]
[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.RequestNumber)]
public string RequestNumber { get; set; } = default!;

[MaxLength(255)]
[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.AgentId)]
public string? AgentId { get; set; }

[MaxLength(255)]
[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.QueueNumber)]
public string? QueueNumber { get; set; }

[MaxLength(20)]
[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.ReceptionNumber)]

public string? ReceptionNumber { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(20)]
[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.PhoneNumber)]
public string CallerPhoneNumber { get; set; } = default!;

[Required]
[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.OutboundType)]
public CallOutboundType OutboundType { get; set; }

[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.Annotation)]
public string? Annotation { get; set; }

[Required]
[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.IsRead)]
public bool IsRead { get; set; }

[Required]
[Column(Constants.Column.CallerRequestEntity.SpecialTransfer)]
public bool SpecialTransfer { get; set; }
```

Comment: что такое `CallerRequestEntity` и почему оно нарушает ограничения `<T>` для `Repository<T>`?

Comment: `SwitchViewedReportCommand.SwitchViewedReportCommand` старайтесь избегать названий классов совпадающих с пространством имен и наоборот.

Comment: Я может глупость сейчас скажу, но разве EF не является уже репозиторием? Другими словами, не масло ли это масленное?

Comment: @tym32167 да вот это и не понятно )
Я добавирл вниз поста содержимое этой Entity. Правада, как-то коряво код вставился.

Comment: Я всегда считал, что MediatR - никчёмная приблуда. Только усложняет разработку.

Comment: Ну вы в коде можете написать что то типа `var repo = new Repository<CallerRequestEntity>();` и глянуть что за ошибку выдаст компилятор на это